# DecodeURI for query parameter in URL does not work

Tags: javascript

Since the `value` parameter has characters that are not read, such as the `" "` where the value is found where it is encountered, I tried to pass in the URL in reference to the decodeURI `value` but it doesn't work.

Can you kindly help me with this?

```js
<a href="updatebook.html?id=${item.id}&number=${item.number}&value=decodeURI${item.value}">${item.type}</a>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you want to read these values from url or encode this value in the href?

Comment: Suppose the value is: `Hi "Tim"` .. When I pass this parameter, it is not passed to me in full, because it only passes `Hi`, without `Tim`. It is cut off when he meets the `" "`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 problems with your code.

The first is that you are using `decodeURI` function but you should use `encodeURI` function.

The second problem is that you are not calling the function, you forgot the `(` and `)`.

**Update:**

As pointed out by @deceze, the third problem is the function call needs to be inside the `${}`.

All put together, it should be:

```js
const item = {
    id: 1,
  value: 'https://stackoverflow.com?q=hello world',
  type: 'bar'
};

let link = `<a href="updatebook.html?id=${item.id}&number=${item.number}&value=${encodeURI(item.value)}">${item.type}</a>`;

console.log(link);
```

Comment: Nothing happens. It does the same thing

Comment: Suppose the value is: `Hi "Tim"` .. When I pass this parameter, it is not passed to me in full, because it only passes `Hi`, without `Tim`. It is cut off when he meets the `" "`

Comment: Ok, but where is that code? Is this a react app?

Comment: So I notice that it also passes me along with the parameter `"encodeURI("`

Comment: The function call needs to be inside the `${}`…

Comment: @deceze Yes, I'm updating my answer to reflect that. Nice catch!